# Finding the mean of a column

Tags: r, dataframe, mean

Using R, I am trying to find the mean of a column but I can't seem to get it to work. This is my code:

```
mean(data_frame$column, na.rm = TRUE)
```

When I run it it just gives me an error message: `argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA`. I've tried also using `colMeans` by it just give another error message: `'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please show the `str(data_frame)`

Comment: Check the class of your data 

`class(data_frame$column)`

Comment: The class is a data.frame. For the str(data_frame), what do you want me to show? I'm new to R so I don't think I know that. I ran it in my console but do you want me to copy and paste the whole output?

Comment: Please read the instructions for posting at the top of the [tag:r] tag page.

Comment: If `class(data_frame$column)` is data.frame then you might need `mean(data_frame$column$another_column, na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: What is the class of the variable, which you can check using `class(data_frame$column)`? It sounds like you checked `class(data_frame)` and saw that the class is a data.frame. You probably have to do something like `data_frame$column <- as.numeric(data_frame$column)` to set the variable class to numeric before trying to take the mean.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should normalize your data first, then calculate your mean

```
# remove NA value
data_frame <- data_frame[!(is.na(data_frame$column) | data_frame$column==""),]
# calculate the mean
mean <- mean(data_frame[["column"]])
```

let me know if this works for you